# Writing to a Yaml file

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using python to write in to a YAML file. But I am unable to write it in a specific format as I require

```
  awesome_people:
    name: Awesome People
    entities:
      - device_tracker.dad_smith
      - device_tracker.mom_smith
```

I am getting problem in the **entities** part, as I am unable to create a list with proper indents as in the above YAML.

How can I create the above exact format?

Comment: Unless you parse the resulting file with something else than a standard YAML parser, the actual formatting/indentation of sequences should not matter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `ruamel.yaml`, setting the sequence indent from default two to four,
and the offset of the dash+space (which need a minimum indent of two), from zero to two.
You should leave the mapping indent unchanged from the default:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

ent = ['device_tracker.dad_smith', 'device_tracker.mom_smith']
data = dict(awesome_people = dict(name='Awesome People', entities=ent))

yaml_str = """\
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
awesome_people:
  name: Awesome People
  entities:
    - device_tracker.dad_smith
    - device_tracker.mom_smith
```